# Make :focus styling remain there after the user clicks the link

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, mobile

I have created a mobile hamburger menu with several links. You can examine the source code here:

```
<div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="da3c1dd" class="elementor-element elementor-element-da3c1dd elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-element_type="spacer.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
            <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="5fa72fd" class="elementor-element elementor-element-5fa72fd elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="regulation-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#regulation-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">?מהי רגולציה</span></span></a></h4>       </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="4e7c2bc" class="elementor-element elementor-element-4e7c2bc elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#mayaaboutmob"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">אודות</span></span></a></h4>       </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="45788e2" class="elementor-element elementor-element-45788e2 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#fit-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">?למי זה מתאים</span></span></a></h4>     </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="2a24b44" class="elementor-element elementor-element-2a24b44 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#solution-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">פתרונות</span></span></a></h4>      </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="fcd1ddb" class="elementor-element elementor-element-fcd1ddb elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="contact-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#contact-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">צור קשר</span></span></a></h4>       </div>
                </div>
                <section data-id="23d1d02" class="elementor-element elementor-element-23d1d02 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-inner-section" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                <div class="elementor-row">
                <div data-id="b6d5052" class="elementor-element elementor-element-b6d5052 column-contact elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-inner-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="4f72658" class="elementor-element elementor-element-4f72658 mobilemenucontact elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" id="mobilemenucontact" data-element_type="text-editor.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix"><p class="makeSmall" style="text-align: center;"><img class="email-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-1.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;<img class="facebook-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-2.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;<label style="color: #61f6ff;" data-mce-fragment="1">|&nbsp;<span style="color: #001a71;" data-mce-fragment="1">&nbsp;052-6582643</span></label></p></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="3829e8b" class="elementor-element elementor-element-3829e8b elementor-widget elementor-widget-html" data-element_type="html.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() { 
jQuery('.menu-item-text').on('click',function(){ jQuery('.menu-item-text').removeClass('active'); jQuery(this).addClass('active'); }); 
});

</script>

            </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </section>
                        </div>
```

Once the user clicks one of the links in the menu, the menu closes and he is navigated to wherever he clicked. I want the border effect I created with CSS to remain there, so he'll have a mark where he is in the navigation:

```
#menu-solutions:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menu-solutions:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menu-solutions:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
        padding: 4px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
margin-bottom: 4px;



}

#about-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text, 
#about-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text, 
#about-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
        padding: 4px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
margin-bottom: 4px;


}
#contact-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text, 
#contact-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text, 
#contact-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
        padding: 4px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
margin-bottom: 4px;

}
#regulation-menu-mobile:hover .menu-item-text, 
#regulation-menu-mobile:focus .menu-item-text, 
#regulation-menu-mobile:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
        padding: 4px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            margin-bottom: 4px;


}

#menu-solutions .menu-item-text {
  border-bottom: 2.11px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 2.11px solid transparent;    
  padding: 4px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

You can also examine the link: [www.mayabarber.co.il](http://www.mayabarber.co.il)
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to use `:visited`?

Comment: `:visited` will apply to every `<a>` with visited URL, which is not what OP wants to achieve. What OP is asking for can't be done without additional CSS class applied to current's route `<a>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. Just replace your above CSS code with this one:

```
.elementor-widget-wrap .elementor-heading-title > a:hover .menu-item-text, 
.elementor-widget-wrap .elementor-heading-title > a:focus .menu-item-text, 
.elementor-widget-wrap .elementor-heading-title > a:active .menu-item-text,
.elementor-widget-wrap .elementor-heading-title > a .menu-item-text.active{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
padding: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u071skpa/10/)

Comment: If you could explain what was wrong with OP's code and why this works, that would be of great help to the future readers.

Answer (score 3):

I guess defining style for active class should work for you.

```css
.active {
  border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I have applied active attributes to every ID

Comment: But at any given time, the active class would apply to only one menu item which would be active at that instant.