# How to select a currently open link in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu bar with 3 links `(Home (class="h")`, `Contact (class="c")`, `About(class="A")`). Now currently the Home page is open so i want the `background color` of Home (`class="h"`) link to be `green` and the `background color` of other 2 links to be `black`.

Comment: Does [this MDN page on :target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [51008517](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008517/make-focus-styling-remain-there-after-the-user-clicks-the-link).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Jquery code to do this. See an example here: https://codepen.io/Nacorga/pen/rKryYL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul {
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
        width: 33.33333%;
        background: #000;
        height: 60px;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    li:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 60px;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: green; 
    }

</style>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li class="h">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="c">
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="a">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        let count = $('li').length;

        for (let i = 0; i< count; i++) {

            $($('li')[i]).click(function() {

                $('li').removeClass('active');
                $($('li')[i]).addClass('active');

            });

        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```